# How to use left over space in wpf tab items row

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

Upper part of TabControl consists of TabItem controls. Is there a way to reuse remaining space there to put some WPF content?

I think I could use a "fake" TabItem with different styling and put my stuff in TabItem.Header but I was hoping there's a better way.

**Solution**

Based on the answer below, I got the desired behavior by wrapping TabPanel in the template below within e.g. StackPanel and adding my additional content after it.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TabPanel 
    Grid.Row="0"
    Panel.ZIndex="1" 
    Margin="0,0,4,-1" 
    IsItemsHost="True"
    Background="Transparent" />
    <TextBlock>Foo</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a template and make it do whatever you want, that is the power of WPF.  [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out) is a nice article on customizing the TabControl and the TabItem controls.

< EDIT Adding code for TabControl template from Switch On The Code article>

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TabPanel 
             Grid.Row="0"
             Panel.ZIndex="1" 
             Margin="0,0,4,-1" 
             IsItemsHost="True"
             Background="Transparent" />
          <Border 
             Grid.Row="1"
             BorderBrush="Black" 
             BorderThickness="1" 
             CornerRadius="0, 12, 12, 12" >
            <Border.Background>
              <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
              </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

all you have to do is add your content to the Template, the part that holds the tab items is the `<TabControl>`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I've seen many articles describing how to modify the look of TabItem (including the one you linked to).

What I'm asking, however, is how to use the space *after* TabItem(s).

Comment: ahh, but it DOES answer your question. Look about 1/2 way down where he redefines the control template for the tab control.  All you have to do is modify the template for the tab control, placing whatever you want in that area after the <TabPanel>

Comment: Thanks, that explanation was helpful. I got what I wanted by wrapping TabPanel within e.g. StackPanel.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a different way, which was to create another grid that occupies the same space as the TabControl, ie both are in Grid.Row=0. I have bound the grid height to the height of the first tab so if the tabs change height the other controls will remain centered. I set MinWidth on the window so the controls dont overlap the tabs.

Paste this code into a new WPF Window...

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="306" Width="490" MinWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem x:Name="tabItem" Header="TabItem" Height="50">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=tabItem}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,2,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" FontSize="16" 
                       Foreground="Red" FontFamily="Calibri">My Text</TextBlock>
            <Button Content="My Button" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

...and you will get this:

[image: Adding controls in empty space next to tabcontrol tabs]